# Reflections are pixelated in eevee, any idea how to solve the issue? I am adding the pic for reference

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, emission

[image]

Using color ramp, noise texture, bump to create the mud texture, but what's the reason I am getting the pixelated reflections.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Eevee reflections are a bit fickle because of the type of rendering it uses. There are a lot of workarounds. You may need to play around with some of the settings, bake a reflection map, use a reflection plane, etc. to achieve the look you desire. You can also opt to use Cycles.

Comment: Hello and welcome, thanks for taking the time to answer. "*Play around with some settings*" is really not an acceptable answer. Could you expand on which settings the user should look into and how? Perhaps illustrate how they help with some screenshots

Comment: Not helping @J. Chan